# What is the influence of "effort put into pursuing wealth" on happiness?

Tags: well-being, economics, positive-psychology

As presented in the [TED talk by Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi](http://www.ted.com/talks/mihaly_csikszentmihalyi_on_flow.html) (3:30) repeated research has been unable to show a correlation between happiness and level of material wealth (above a certain minimum threshold).

As a result, a line of reasoning that is often made is:

> "We should stop pursuing more wealth, since attaining it will not make
>   us happier."

While i agree that we can conclude from this research that ***attaining*** more wealth will not make us happier, i don't think we can conclude that the amount of effort we put into ***pursuing*** more wealth has no influence on our happiness.

There is anecdotal material to show that putting less effort into the pursuit of wealth makes you happier, take Zen monks for example, but there are a lot of other factors that could be causing their increase in happiness.

- **What research has examined the merit/effect of detachment from material wealth?**
- **To what extent is pursuing or not pursuing wealth related to happiness?**

EDIT:
Happiness, as roughly defined by [any of the known](http://www.howellfoundation.org/Upload/Events/9-25-12Intentional%20Happiness/IntentionalHappinessResearchArticles.pdf) [measurement](http://www.ppc.sas.upenn.edu/subjectivehappinessscale.pdf) [methods](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0191886901002136).

Comment: Voluntary poverty as a concept comes to mind. In the modern America there are also people who advocate "less is more"- in general this means owning less stuff.

Comment: Thanks, googling on "voluntary poverty" gave me this article. Quite interesting, since it mentions a lot of findings that seem to contradict the data of Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi, and it makes some points in the direction of what i'm looking for: http://bridgesandtangents.wordpress.com/tag/voluntary-poverty/

Comment: It might be worth looking at this question from the perspective of success; if success is important in personal happiness, wealthy people who did not succeed on their own terms (who inherited, for example) might have very different "happiness" than wealthy people who are wealthy because they succeeded at something.  Possibly also relevant is how exactly happiness is operationalized (contentment/satisfaction? joy? lack of negative affect?) and whether different operational definitions would give different answers.

Comment: Good question (+1) I don't have an answer but note that jumping from a (apparently) cross-sectional absence of link to a causal story of the kind presented by Csikszentmihalyi is a little questionable. That richer people do not report being happier on average does not mean they, personally, would not be less happy if they were poorer (and vice versa).

Comment: Apparently there's research out there showing that -having- goals is essential to happiness, but achieving them is not necessarily so. That goals function as a tool to provide happiness in the present. I'll get back if i find some references.

Comment: Did you thoroughly search for an answer before asking your question? I believe the premise is poorly constructed and attracts opinionated discussion (qq.v. comments) instead of a concise factual answer. See the [How to Ask](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help. The "question" requires accepting assumptions (conclusions) that are contestable. A respondent is required to define happiness -- which is debatable.  Objective happiness, preferentialism, sensory hedonism, well-being or satisfactionism? Is happiness confined to past, present, or future perceptions? vote2close

Comment: I don't see why the question should be limited to one specific "type" of happiness. It would already be a nice and useful answer if there was -any- clue on -any- type of happiness. But for clarity, i've added some references to ways of measuring how happiness is (most) commonly interpreted: a general sense of well-being and satisfaction, now, and over a more extended period of time.

Comment: I failed to distinguish my three objections. Mostly, the question as framed, requires that we accept both your assumption and conclusion that "that attaining more wealth will not make us happier". Such a conclusion requires a leap-of-faith and a stomach full of recursive assumptions. It is simply provocation at this juncture to presume SWB is little more than pseudo-science. As the question of pursuit is built upon a fallacious foundation of attainment, the question is invalid. Can the pursuit question stand on its own merits without assumptive challenges or comingled with other research? No.

Comment: That said, in the spirit of good faith, I've done my best to reach across the divide with an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In alignment with the question author's commentary refinement, *"It would already be a nice and useful answer if there was -any- clue on -any- type of happiness."*:

## I submit:

[Stevenson, Betsey, and Justin Wolfers. "Subjective Well-Being and Income: Is There Any Evidence of Satiation?" American Economic Review 103.3 (2013): 598-604. Web.](http://www.brookings.edu/~/media/research/files/papers/2013/04/subjective%20well%20being%20income/subjective%20well%20being%20income.pdf)

Abstract

> Many scholars have argued that once “basic needs” have been met, higher income is no longer associated with higher in subjective well-being. We assess the validity of this claim in comparisons of both rich and poor countries, and also of rich and poor people within a country. Analyzing multiple datasets, multiple definitions of “basic needs” and multiple questions about well-being, we find no support for this claim. The relationship between well-being and income is roughly linear-log and does not diminish as incomes rise. If there is a satiation point, we are yet to reach it.

Summary of findings:

> To preview, we find no evidence of a satiation point. The income–well-being link that one finds when examining only the poor, is similar to that found when examining only the rich. We show that this finding is robust across a variety of datasets, for various measures of subjective well-being, at various thresholds, and that it holds in roughly equal measure when making cross-national comparisons between rich and poor countries as when making comparisons between rich and poor people within a country.

---

- Clark, Andrew E., Paul Frijters, and Michael A. Shields. "Relative Income, Happiness and
  Utility: An Explanation for the Easterlin Paradox and Other Puzzles." Journal of Economic
  Literature 46, no. 1 (2008): 95-144.
- Deaton, Angus "Income, Health, and Well-Being around the World: Evidence from the Gallup
  World Poll." Journal of Economic Perspectives, 2008 22(2), pp. 53-72.
- Di Tella, Rafael, and Robert MacCulloch. Happiness Adaptation to Income beyond "Basic
  Needs". NBER Working Paper, National Bureau of Economic Research, 2008.
- Diener, Ed, and Martin E.P. Seligman. "Beyond money: Toward an economy of well-being." 
  Psychological Science in the Public Interest 5 (2004): 1-31.
- Easterlin, Richard A. "Does economic growth improve the human lot? Some empirical evidence." In 
  Nations and Households in Economic Growth: Essays in Honor of Moses Abramowitz, by Paul A David and 
  Melvin W. Reder. New York: Academic Press, Inc., 1974.
- Easterlin, Richard A., and Onnicha Sawangfa. Happiness and Economic Growth: Does the Cross Section 
  Predict Time Trends? Evidence from Developing Countries. mimeo, University of Southern California, 
  2009.
- Frey, Bruno S., and Alois Stutzer. "What Can Economists Learn from Happiness Research?" Journal of 
  Economic Literature 40 (2002): 402-435.
- Kahneman, Daniel and Angus Deaton. “High Income Improves Evaluation of Life But Not
  Emotional Well-Being” Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, September 7 2010,
  107(38) 16489-16493.
- Layard, Richard. "Happiness: Has Social Science a Clue." Lionel Robbins Memorial Lectures
  2002/3. London School of Economics, 2003.
- —. Happiness: Lessons from a New Science. London: Penguin, 2005.
- Oswald, Andrew J. "On the Curvature of the Reporting Function from Objective Reality to
  Subjective Feelings." Economics Letters, 2008.
- Sacks, Daniel, Betsey Stevenson, and Justin Wolfers “The New Stylized Facts About Income and 
  Subjective Well-being”, Emotion, Dec 2012, 12 (6): 1181-1187
- Sacks, Daniel, Betsey Stevenson, and Justin Wolfers “Growth in Subjective Well-being and
  Income over Time”, 2013 mimeo.
- Stevenson, Betsey, and Justin Wolfers. "Economic Growth and Happiness: Reassessing the
  Easterlin Paradox." Brookings Papers on Economic Activity, Spring 2008: 1-87

---

## In contrast...

[Diener, Ed, and Biswas-Diener, Robert. "Will Money Increase Subjective Well-Being?" Social Indicators Research 57.2 (2002): 119-169. Web.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014411319119)

Abstract (reformatted for ease of reading)

> Four replicable findings have emerged regarding the relation between income and subjective well-being (SWB):
>
> 1. There are large correlations between the wealth of nations and the mean reports of SWB in them,
> 2. There are mostly small correlations between income and SWB within nations, although these correlations appear to be larger in poor nations, and the risk of unhappiness is much higher for poor people,
> 3. Economic growth in the last decades in most economically developed societies has been accompanied by little rise in SWB, and increases in individual income lead to variable outcomes, and
> 4. People who prize material goals more than other values tend to be substantially less happy, unless they are rich.
>
> Thus, more money may enhance SWB when it means avoiding poverty and living in a developed nation, but income appears to increase SWB little over the long-term when more of it is gained by well-off individuals whose material desires rise with their incomes. Several major theories are compatible with most existing findings:
>
> - The idea that income enhances SWB only insofar as it helps people meet their basic needs, and
> - The idea that the relation between income and SWB depends on the amount of material desires that people's income allows them to fulfil[].
>
> We argue that the first explanation is a special case of the second one. A third explanation is relatively unresearched, the idea that societal norms for production and consumption are essential to understanding the SWB-income interface. In addition, it appears high SWB might increase people's chances for high income. We review the open issues relating income to SWB, and describe the research methods needed to provide improved data that will better illuminate the psychological processes relating money to SWB.

---

- Adelmann, P.K.: 1987, 'Occupational complexity, control, and personal income: Their relation to psychological well-being in men and women', Journal of Applied Psychology 72, pp. 529-537.
- Ahuvia, A.C. and N. Wong: in press, 'The development of personality and values based materialisms', Journal of Consumer Psychology.
- Ahuvia, A.C. and N. Wong: 2001, Cognitive and affective antecedents of materialism: Implications for the development of materialism as a political orientation. Manuscript submitted for publication.
- Aldwin, C.M. and T.A. Revenson: 1986, 'Vulnerability to economic stress', American Journal of Community Psychology 14, pp. 161-175.
- Alesina, A., R. DiTella and R. MacCulloch: 2001, Inequality and happiness: Are Europeans and Americans different? Manuscript submitted for publication, Harvard University.
- Andrews, F.M. and S.B. Withey: 1976, Social Indicators of Well-being: America's Perception of Life Quality (Plenum Press, New York).
- Aristotle: 1969, The Nichomachean Ethics, translated by Robert Williams (Longmans, Green, London).
- Biswas-Diener, R. and E. Diener: 2001, 'Making the best of a bad situation: Satisfaction in the slums of Calcutta', Social Indicators Research 55, pp. 329-352.
- Black, D.: 1976, The Behavior of Law (Academic Press, New York).
- Blanchflower, D.G. and A.J. Oswald: 1999, Well-being over Time in Britain and the U.S.A.
- Blanchflower, D.G., A.J. Oswald and P.B. Warr: 1993, Well-being over time in Britain and the USA. Paper presented at the CEP Conference on the Economics and Psychology of Happiness and Fairness.
- Bowen, W.G. and D.C. Bok: 1998, The Shape of the River: Long-term Consequences of Considering Race in College and University Admissions (Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ).
- Bradburn, N.M.: 1969, The Structure of Psychological Well-being (Aldine, Chicago).
- Brant, M., B. Stone, N. Joseph, T.T. Gegax A. Underwood, A. Arora and A. Davis: 1999, 'They're rich and you're not', Newsweek, July 5, vol. 134, pp. 36-43.
- Brinkerhoff, M.B., K.A. Fredell and J.S. Frideres: 1997, 'Basic minimum needs, quality of life and selected correlates: Exploration in villages in northern India', Social Indicators Research 42, pp. 245-281.
- Brickman, P., D. Coates and R. Janoff-Bulman: 1978, 'Lottery winners and accident victims: Is happiness relative?' Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 36, pp. 917-927.
- Campbell, A.: 1981, The Sense of Well-being in America (McGraw-Hill, New York).
- Campbell, A., P.E. Converse and W.L. Rodgers: 1976, The Quality of American Life (Russell Sage, New York).
- Clark, A.: 1999, 'Are wages habit forming? Evidence from micro data', Journal of Economic Behavior and Organization 39, pp. 179-200.
- Clark, A., E. Diener and Y. Georgellis: 2000, July, Lags and leads in life satisfaction: A test of the baseline hypothesis. Paper presented at the German Socio-Economic Panel Conference 2000, Berlin.
- Clark, A.E. and A.J. Oswald: 1994, 'Unhappiness and unemployment', Economic Journal 104, pp. 648-659.
- Clark, A.E. and A.J. Oswald: 1996, 'Satisfaction and comparison income', Journal of Public Economics 61, pp. 359-381.
- Clydesdale, T.T.: 1997, 'Family behaviors among early U.S. baby boomers: Exploring the effects of religion and income change, 1965–1982', Social Forces 76, pp. 605-635.
- Crawford, E., E. Diener, S. Oishi and S. Wirtz: 2000, Desires as a standard explaining income satisfaction. Manuscript submitted for publication, University of Illinois.
- Csikszentmihalyi, M.: 1997, Finding Flow (Basic Books, New York).
- Csikszentmihalyi, M.: 1999, 'If we are so rich, why aren't we happy?' American Psychologist 54, pp. 821-827.
- Csikszentmihalyi, M. and B. Schneider: in press, Becoming Adults: How Teenagers Prepare for Work (Basic Books, New York).
- Deci, E.L. and R.M. Ryan: 1980, 'Self-determination theory: When mind mediates behavior', Journal of Mind and Behavior 1, pp. 33-43.
- Diener, E.: 1984, 'Subjective well-being', Psychological Bulletin 95, pp. 542-575.
- Diener, E. and C. Diener: 1995a, 'The wealth of nations revisited: Income and quality of life', Social Indicators Research 36, pp. 275-286.
- Diener, E. and C. Diener: 1996, 'Most people are happy', Psychological Science 7, pp. 181-185.
- Diener, E. and M. Diener: 1995b, 'Cross cultural correlates of life satisfaction and self-esteem', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 68, pp. 653-663.
- Diener, E., M. Diener and C. Diener: 1995, 'Factors predicting the subjective well-being of nations', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 69, pp. 851-864.
- Diener, E., J. Horwitz and R.A. Emmons: 1985, 'Happiness of the very wealthy', Social Indicators Research 16, pp. 263-274.
- Diener, E. and R.E. Lucas: 2000, 'Explaining differences in societal levels of happiness: Relative standards, need fulfillment, culture, and evaluation theory', Journal of Happiness Studies 1, pp. 41-78.
- Diener, E., C. Nickerson, R.E. Lucas and E. Sandvik: 2000, Do happy people earn more money? The causal relation of income and subjective well-being. Manuscript submitted for publication, University of Illinois.
- Diener, E. and S. Oishi: 2000, 'Money and happiness: Income and subjective well-being across nations', in E. Diener and E.M. Suh (eds.), Subjective Well-being across Cultures (MIT Press, Cambridge, MA).
- Diener, E., R. E. Lucas, S. Oishi and E. M. Suh: in press, 'Looking up and looking down: Weighting good and bad information in life satisfaction judgments', Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin.
- Diener, E., E. Sandvik, L. Seidlitz and M. Diener: 1993, 'The relationship between income and subjective well-being: Relative or absolute?' Social Indicators Research 28, pp. 195-223.
- Diener, E., C. Scollon, S. Oishi, V. Dzokoto and E.M. Suh: 2000, 'Positivity and the construction of life satisfaction judgments: Global happiness is not the sum of its parts', Journal of Happiness Studies 1, pp. 159-176.
- Diener, E., E.M. Suh, R.E. Lucas and H.L. Smith: 1999, 'Subjective well-being: Three decades of progress', Psychological Bulletin 125, pp. 276-302.
- Dittmar, H.: 1992, 'Perceived material wealth and first impressions', British Journal of Social Psychology 31, pp. 379-391.
- Dooley, D., R. Catalano and A. Brownell: 1986, 'The relation of economic conditions, social support, and life events to depression', Journal of Community Psychology 14, pp. 103-119.
- Dooley, D., R. Catalano, K. Rook and S. Serxner: 1989, 'Economic stress and suicide: Multilevel time-series analyses of economic stress and suicide', Suicide & Life-Threatening Behavior 19, pp. 321-336.
- Douthitt, R.A., M. MacDonald and R. Mullis: 1992, 'The relationship between measures of subjective and economic well-being: A newlook', Social Indicators Research 26, pp. 407-422.
- Dow, G.K. and F.T. Juster: 1985, 'Goods, time, and well-being: The joint dependence problem', in F.T. Juster and F.P. Stafford (eds.), Time, Goods, and Well-being (Institute for Social Research, Ann Arbor, MI).
- Droge, C., R. Calantos, M. Agrawal and R. Mackoy: 1993, 'The consumption culture and its critiques: A framework for analysis', Journal of Macromarketing 13, pp. 32-45.
- Easterlin, R.A.: 1974, 'Does economic growth improve the human lot? Some empirical evidence', in P.A. David and M.W. Reder (eds.), Nations and Households in Economic Growth (Academic Press, New York, pp. 89-125).
- Easterlin, R.A.: 1996, Growth Triumphant: The Twenty-first Century in Historical Perspective (University of Michigan Press, Ann Arbor).
- Easterlin, R.A.: 1999, Life cycle welfare: Evidence and conjecture. Unpublished paper, University of Southern California.
- Frank, R.H.: 1999, Luxury Fever: Why Money Fails to Satisfy in an Era of Excess (The Free Press, New York).
- Frey, B.S. and A. Stutzer: 2000, 'Happiness, economy and institutions', The Economic Journal 110, pp. 918-938.
- Furnham, A. and M. Argyle: 1998, The Psychology of Money (Routledge, London).
- Gardner, J. and A. Oswald: 2001, Does money buy happiness? A longitudinal study using data on windfalls. Manuscript submitted for publication.
- George, L.K.: 1992, 'Economic status and subjective well-being: A review of the literature and an agenda for future research', in N.E. Cutler, D.W. Gregg and M.P. Lawton (eds.), Aging, Money, and Life Satisfaction: Aspects of Financial Gerontology (Springer, New York).
- Hagerty, M.R.: 1998, 'Unifying livability and comparison theory: Cross-national time-series analysis of life-satisfaction', Social Indicators Research 47, pp. 343-356.
- Hagerty, M.R.: 2000, 'Social comparisons of income in one's community: Evidence from national surveys of income and happiness', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 78, pp. 764-771.
- Hagerty, M.R. and R. Veenhoven: 1999, Wealth and happiness revisited: Growing wealth of nations does go with greater happiness. Unpublished manuscript, University of California, Davis.
- Hamermesh, D.S.: 2001, 'The changing distribution of job satisfaction', The Journal of Human Resources 36, pp. 1-30.
- Hampson, R.: 1998, 'Eleanor Boyer's generosity provides inspiration for many', U.S.A. Today, April 10-12, 1A-2A.
- Herriott, R.A.: 1977, 'Collecting income data on sample surveys: Evidence from split-panel studies', Journal of Marketing Research 14, pp. 322-329.
- Inglehart, R. and H.D. Klingemann: 2000, 'Genes, culture, and happiness', in E. Diener and E.M. Suh (eds.), Subjective Well-being across Cultures (MIT Press, Cambridge, MA).
- Inglehart, R. and J.R. Rabier: 1986, 'Aspirations adapt to situations–But why are the Belgians so much happier than the French? A cross-cultural analysis of the subjective quality of life', in F.M. Andrews (ed.), Research on Quality of Life (Survey Research Center, Ann Arbor, MI).
- Inkeles, A. and L. Diamond: 1980, 'Personal development and national development: A cross-national perspective', in A. Szalai and F.M. Andrews (eds.), The Quality of Life: Comparative Studies (Sage, Beverly Hills, CA).
- Juster, F.T., 1985, 'Preferences for work and leisure', in F.T. Juster and F.P. Stafford (eds.), Time, Goods, and Well-being (Institute for Social Research, Ann Arbor, MI).
- Kahneman, D., 1999, 'Objective happiness', in D. Kahneman, E. Diener and N. Schwarz (eds.), Well-being: The Foundations of Hedonic Psychology (Russell Sage Foundation, New York, pp. 3-25).
- Kahneman, D. and A. Tversky: 1984, 'Choices, values, and frames', American Psychologist 39, pp. 341-350.
- Kapteyn, A., B.M.S. Praag and F.G. van Herwaarden: 1976, 'Individual welfare functions and social reference spaces', Economic Letters 1, pp. 173-178.
- Kasser, T.: 2000, 'Two versions of the American Dream: Which goals and values make for a high quality of life?' in E. Diener and D.R. Rahtz (eds.), Advances in Quality of Life Theory and Research, Volume 1 (Kluwer, Dordrecht, Netherlands, pp. 3-12).
- Kasser, T. and R.M. Ryan: 1993, 'A dark side of the American Dream: Correlates of financial success as a central life aspiration', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 65, pp. 410-422.
- Keith, P.M.: 1985, 'Financial well-being of older divorced/separated men and women: Findings from a panel study', Journal of Divorce 9, pp. 61-72.
- Keith, P.M. and R.B. Schafer: 1982, 'A comparison of depression among employed single-parent and married women', Journal of Psychology 110, pp. 239-247.
- Lachman, M.E. and S.L. Weaver: 1998, 'The sense of control as a moderator of social class differences in health and well-being', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 74, pp. 763-773.
- Lane, R.E.: 1991, The Market Experience (Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK).
- Langner, T.S. and S.T. Michael: 1963, Life Stress and Mental Health (Free Press, New York).
- Lehman, J.S. and T.M. Smeeding: 1997, 'Neighborhood effects and federal policy', in J. Brooks-Gunn, G. J. Duncan and J. L. Aber (eds.), Neighborhood Poverty, vol. 1 (Russell Sage Foundation), pp. 251-278.
- Liker, J.K. and G.H. Elder: 1983, 'Economic hardship and marital relations in the 1930's', American Sociological Review 48, pp. 343-359.
- Marks, G.N. and N. Fleming: 1999, 'Influences and consequences of well-being among Australian young people: 1980–1995', Social Indicators Research 46, pp. 301-323.
- Mayer, S.E.: 1997, 'Indicators of children's economic well-being and parental employment', in R.M. Hauser, B.V. Brown and W.R. Prosser (eds.), Indicators of Children's Well-being (Russell Sage Foundation, New York).
- Mayer, S.E.: 1997, What Money Can't Buy: Family Income and Children's Life Chances (Harvard University Press, Cambridge, MA).
- McClelland, D.C. and C.E. Franz: 1992, 'Motivational and other sources of work accomplishments in mid-life: A longitudinal study', Journal of Personality 60, pp. 679-707.
- Michalos, A.C.: 1985, 'Multiple discrepancies theory (MDT)', Social Indicators Research 16, pp. 347-413.
- Mitchell, T.R., L. Thompson, E. Peterson and R. Cronk: 1997, 'Temporal adjust-ments in the evaluations of events: The “rosy view”,' Journal of Experimental Social Psychology 33, pp. 421-448.
- Mullis, R.J.: 1992, 'Measures of economic well-being as predictors of psychological well-being', Social Indicators Research 26, pp. 119-135.
- Nakosteen, R.A. and M.A. Zimmer: 1997, 'Men, money, and marriage: Are high earners more prone than low earners to marry?' Social Service Quarterly 78, pp. 66-82.
- Nickerson, C., N. Schwarz, D. Kahneman and E. Diener: 2001, The American Dream: The dark side is in the wish, not the realization. Manuscript submitted for publication.
- Oishi, S. and E. Diener: 2000, Remembering versus experiencing well-being: The case of Asian-Americans and European-Americans. Manuscript in preparation, University of Illinois.
- Oswald, A.J.: 1997, 'Happiness and economic performance', The Economic Journal 107, pp. 1815-1831.
- Ouweneel, P. and R. Veenhoven: 1991, 'Cross-national differences in happiness: Cultural bias or societal quality', in N. Bleichrodt and P.J. Drenth (eds.), Contemporary Issues in Cross-cultural Psychology (Swets & Zeitlinger, Amsterdam).
- Pamuk, E., D. Makuc, K. Heck, C. Reuben and K. Lochner: 1998, Socioeconomic Status and Health Chartbook: Health, United States, 1998 (National Center for Health Statistics, Hyattsville, MD).
- Parducci, A.: 1995, Happiness, Pleasure, and Judgment: The Contextual Theory and Its Applications (Erlbaum, Mahwah, NJ).
- Pearlin, L.I. and J.S. Johnson: 1977, 'Marital status, life strains and depressions', American Sociological Review 42, pp. 704-715.
- Richins, M.L. and S. Dawson: 1992, 'A consumer values orientation for materialism and its measurement: Scale development and validation', Journal of Consumer Research 19, pp. 303-316.
- Rosenberg, M. and L.E. Pearlin: 1978, 'Social class and self-esteem among children and adults', American Journal of Sociology 84, pp. 54-58.
- Ross, C.E. and J. Huber: 1985, 'Hardship and depression', Journal of Health and Social Behavior 26, pp. 312-327.
- Sandvik, E., E. Diener and L. Seidlitz: 1993, 'Subjective well-being: The convergence and stability of self-report and non-self report measures', Journal of Personality 64, pp. 319-341.
- Saris, W.E.: 2001, 'The relationship between income and satisfaction: The effect of measurement error and suppressor variables', Social Indicators Research 53, pp. 117-136.
- Schor, J.B.: 1998, The Overspent American (Basic Books, New York).
- Schwartz, B.: 1994, The Costs of Living: How Market Freedom Erodes the Best Things in Life (W.W. Norton, New York).
- Schwarz, N. and F. Strack: 1999, 'Reports of subjective well-being: Judgmental processes and their methodological implications', in D. Kahneman, E. Diener and N. Schwarz (eds.), Well-being: The Foundations of Hedonic Psychology (Russell Sage Foundation, New York, pp. 61-84).
- Schyns, P.: 1998a, Nation wealth, individual income and life-satisfaction in 42 countries: A multilevel approach. Paper presented at the Second Annual ISQOLS conference. Williamsburg, VA. December 3-6.
- Schyns, P.: 1998b, The Relationship between Wealth of Countries, Individual Income and Life-satisfaction: A Multilevel Approach. Paper presented at ISA XIV World Congress of Sociology, Montreal, Canada, July 26-August 1.
- Schyns, P.: 2000, 'The relationship between income, changes in income and life satisfaction in West Germany and the Russian Federation: Relative, absolute, or a combination of both?' in E. Diener and D.R. Rahtz (eds.), Advances in Quality of Life Theory and Research, Volume 1 (Kluwer, Dordrecht, Netherlands, pp. 83-109).
- Schyns, P.: in press, 'Income and satisfaction in post Communist Russia', Journal of Happiness Studies.
- Sirgy, M.J.: 1997, 'Materialism and quality of life', Social Indicators Research 43, pp. 227-260.
- Smith, J.R., J. Brooks-Gunn and A. Jackson: 1997, 'Parental employment and children', in R.M. Hauser, B.V. Brown and W.R. Prosser (eds.), Indicators of Children's Well-being (Russell Sage Foundation, New York).
- Srivastava, A., E.A. Locke and K.M. Bartol: 2001, 'Money and subjective well-being: It's not the money, it's the motives', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 80, pp. 959-971.
- Smith, S. and P. Razzell: 1975, The Pools' Winners (Calibon Books, London).
- Suh, E. M., E. Diener, S. Oishi and H. Triandis: 1998, 'The shifting basis of life satisfaction judgments across cultures: Emotions versus norms', Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 74, pp. 482-493.
- Sumners, R. and A. Heston: 1991, 'Penn World Table (Mark 5): An expanded set of international comparisons, 1950–1988', Quarterly Journal of Economics 106, pp. 327-368.
- Templeton, J.M.: 1999, 'A worldwide rise in living standards', The Futurist 33, pp. 17-22.
- Thoits, P. and M. Hannan: 1979, 'Income and psychological distress: The impact of an income-maintenance experiment', Journal of Health and Social Behavior 20, pp. 120-138.
- Tomes, N.: 1986, 'Income distribution, happiness, and satisfaction: A direct test of the interdependent preferences model', Journal of Economic Psychology 7, pp. 425-446.
- van Praag, B.M.S.: 1993, 'The relativity of the welfare concept', in M. Nussbaum and A. Sen (eds.), The Quality of Life (Clarendon, Oxford).
- Veenhoven, R.: 1991, 'Is happiness relative?' Social Indicators Research 24, pp. 1-34.
- Veenhoven, R.: 1993, Happiness in Nations: Subjective Appreciation of Life in 55 Nations 1996–1990 (RISBO, Rotterdam).
- Veenhoven, R.: 1995, 'The cross-national pattern of happiness: Test of predictions implied in three theories of happiness', Social Indicators Research 34, pp. 33-68.
- Veenhoven, R. and P. Ouweneel: 1995, 'Livability of the welfare-state', Social Indicators Research 36, pp. 1-48.
- United Nations Development Programme: 1998, Human Development Report–1998 (Oxford University Press, New York).
- Wheaton, B.: 1994, 'Sampling the stress universe', in W.R. Avison and I.H. Gotlib (eds.), Stress and Mental Health (Plenum Press, New York, pp. 77-114).
- Wilkinson, R.G.: 1996, Unhealthy Societies: The Afflictions of Inequality (Routledge, London).
- Wilson, J.B., D.T. Ellwood and J. Brooks-Gunn: 1995, 'Welfare-to-work through the eyes of children', in P.L. Chase-Lansdale and J. Brooks-Gunn (eds.), Escape from Poverty (Cambridge University Press, New York).
- Wirtz, D., C. Scollon, J. Kruger and E. Diener: 2001, Selecting a spring break: On-line versus recalled mood of the last one. Manuscript submitted for publication, University of Illinois.
- World Value Survey Group: 1994, World Values Survey, 1981–1984 and 1990–1993 (Institute for Social Research, ICPSR, Ann Arbor, MI).

---

In spite of the substance in my answer (above), I maintain that the premise and question are poorly framed. Not unlike Neuro-linguistic programming (NLP), I firmly believe that a post-modernist philosophical approach is being employed by this line of research that flirts dangerously close to pseudo-science. While there is little doubting the potential for the sensational, I stand with those who venture that applying immature definitions, as well as, recursive and undeclared assumptions create an illusion of scientific maturity that simply does not exist. Further, the current approach (unintentionally?) advocates unsound scientific short-cuts that, at best, run the risk of gross misinterpretation by lay persons -- while at worst, subject the entire body of knowledge to endless premise challenges. There is very little in this thread of research that is meaningful or actionable outside a very narrow community -- and still, for them, most appropriately, only to conclude that more focus is needed. It can, after all, be considered an advance to get off the blank page and begin scratching away at the "we don't know what we don't know" knowledge boundary. I suppose through Dr. Steven Wright (Visiting scientist, Brain and Language Lab, Georgetown University), I can be more cogent (and diplomatic) on this point.

According to Dr. Steve Wright, it is important for researchers to level set their understanding of the meaning happiness before measuring happiness or interpreting statistics for actionable conclusions. He suggests that, currently, two high-level meanings of happiness have emerged. One is happiness as a transitory emotion, a feeling. He further suggests, there are researchers who seem to think this is all there is, and would define a happy life as nothing more than a tally of emotionally “up” or "down" snapshots. While the completely, separate and distinct alternative meaning has a stronger cognitive component (bias), involving memory and judgment (which introduces entirely different, if not equally subjective challenges to [scientific measurement](http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2011/10/16/scientific-measures-reliability-and-validity/) and [replicability](http://psychcentral.com/encyclopedia/2009/replicability/). Finally, Dr. Wright also suggests the integrity of subjects answers can (should?) be viewed through a lens of disbelief -- that is, *'is a respondent's answer true and accurate or skewed selectively and/or unintentionally?*

> Researchers have not yet come to an agreement about this dichotomy. They’re still quite a ways from being able to shed much light on most of the big questions. What’s really known scientifically advances slowly.

Disclaimer:  With the exception of the final blockquote, I am not purporting to channel Dr. Wright. My representation of him is applied interpretation.

Comment: Since you do not mention all of the references listed, could you please take out the ones not pointed to in this post, and remove the others? The full reference list is still available in your link either way.

Comment: You have put remarkable effort into highlighting the vagueness of my question. Given the conflicting references you provided on even some of the base assumptions the question is built on, i think this serves as a proper answer, in the sense that it shows the current knowledge is not even ready yet to tackle some more fundamental questions. I would suggest leaving the references, a lot of them look very relevant and useful for anyone willing to dig deeper. thx!

Comment: @Wouter, they are simply [the references listed in the publication he links to](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014411319119). No point in repeating 124 references out of context. Without specifying why references are relevant, there is no point in listing them in the first place.

Comment: Ah, in that case i know where to find them later if i want to have a look :) But then they don't really have to be listed here indeed.